# Why recursive feature elimination procedure does not get rid of useless predictors?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, feature-selection, rfe

I am trying to select the best predictors of a variable *y*

*x1* and *x3* are predictors of y, *x2* is correlated to *x1* and *x4* is a dummy variable.

```
library(randomForest);library(caret)
set.seed(123)
x1<-rnorm(1000,sd=.3,mean=-2)
x3<-rnorm(1000,sd=1,mean=.3)
x2<-jitter(x1,amount=1)
x4<-rnorm(1000,sd=4,mean=3)

y<-jitter(3*x1+jitter(x3,amount=2),amount=2)
varImpPlot(randomForest(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,importance=T))
```

[image]

```
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,number=3)
x<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
rfe(x,y,rfeControl=ctrl,sizes=1:4,method="rf")

#...
#The top 4 variables (out of 4):
#x3, x1, x2, x4

cor(x)
#             x1          x2         x3          x4
# x1  1.00000000  0.45351111 0.08647944 -0.02470308
# x2  0.45351111  1.00000000 0.03927750 -0.08157149
# x3  0.08647944  0.03927750 1.00000000  0.04357772
# x4 -0.02470308 -0.08157149 0.04357772  1.00000000
```

- Why does recursive feature elimination procedure tell me to keep all predictors even if it is very clear when looking at variable importance that *x2* and *x4* are useless ?

Comment: This should be moved probably to CrossValidated. Can you update with the output  from the call to `rle` and the importance plot? It can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The importance you visualize with `varImpPlot`, should **not** be used has a stand-alone method to remove non important variables.

First of all, continous variables and categorical variables with more labels will have a higher importance. That can be misleading.

Second, **correlated** predictors can have **low** variable importance. That's the opposite of what you want, sometimes.

Also the importance doesn't tell you how the predictors **together** are related with the response.

I suggest to use the permutation method, where you check for importance by re-estimating the model after you permute one variable (ex: sample(x4)), check how the performance moves, comparing for example `mse` (before and after permutation).

The simple idea is that if a variable is useless the performance won't change much.

Lastly, here are some useful readings.

[Link1](https://www.statistik.uni-dortmund.de/useR-2008/slides/Strobl+Zeileis.pdf)

[Link2](https://watermark.silverchair.com/btq134.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAjkwggI1BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggImMIICIgIBADCCAhsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMg2G6K9UYgoXUUobiAgEQgIIB7FR3WP2YWIqREndPHG_2dRRr1BkLIX7B-9WBLH817OXXO7mGIZ_62E52lXhYzXjmyx-UQb0gEqcBxp3c_zHPIs8RJzAn2gGnVIeeMUc04FBSBCzwe2d1pNUd-ST4YpcNgGpVDCGTfhBLXSIcRdT3vZedpclNRNbaS4woZZB--80QcIIKKwtPdEuvRcXGuarxFydYWRlmje3u1ZCelvc7wgkJ_JI8npmAe4wPw_dhKphS0q4VV6HLvvxvDBBITAsLIhDj37B6tw69N3o0dKwPj7g85DPHSIsSY06JPaI31feELpq6OtUq55j8WDr3iE102nM7kQjFD6rTDIXzW06NpeR_LnlLO6kOcY7mfFaiWhktyRTVHf1dYREmSnozNywlcQ82LC-F6vyQSebxXTqSTFmi6VdvMU4qLinPt5DrEr7Fp20tSCeghce9KOmPcVgMhRAk8dTne3_zHe-3ODiMQd6sRERD_Ljw6NTty5R34snH318gVw36LB5bbLbv3kIRLdDFaPUrqNeEPe7N_BpGXto1bMuLLV4OtvttxyCZM38wFJbNo95CBvEAq3xvGmjlIQi2C9Th_vM8Kz-KZZMBqgiHIgAPiazA45TxGj-L7lTizkub7uWysEm34wkKUtVG0UMyuJHnRr7dRIKG-A)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that importance alone is not enough but here I used rfe to select the predictors (importance plot is only to illustrate the problem). rfe should understand that x2 and x4 are useless or what is the point of this method for predictors selection ??

Comment: well `x2` is correlated with `x1`, how much is this correlation? `corr(x2,x1)` may be sufficently high to make it important.

Comment: don't know about `x4`, at least this shows that one should always doubt automated procedure.

Comment: Agreed, the problem is when there are plenty of correlated predictors ... How to choose ?